# How to get amount in 1,000.00 format

Tags: javascript

I have a number 1000 in an object.

I want it to be in `1,000.00` format

I tried:

```
obj[key] = (parseFloat(obj[key]).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
```

This gives `1000.00`

[image: d]

Comment: i have done what that answers says but i dont get it

Comment: Read the documentation of `toLocaleString`.  It has an option to group digits

Comment: @Amy where is it?

Comment: Google "mdn toLocaleString"

Comment: @Amy i cant check now because the back end is down. but you meant `toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})` right

Comment: @deceze Maybe there's a better duplicate? The requirement to include two decimal places even if the number to be formatted is a whole number is not present in the linked duplicate. There happens to be [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565687/1709587) that does so anyway, but it's a long way down the page after lots of answers that don't satisfy the specific requirements here. (It's also arguably a bad answer to the question it's posted on, and is copied from the source linked without formatting as a quote, in violation of our referencing policy.) I'm tentatively voting to reopen this.

Comment: @Leguy Yes, that and the `useGrouping` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer to account for numbers with no remainder:

Use the options in `toLocaleString();`

Try this:

`obj[key] = obj[key].toLocaleString(undefined,{minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});`

No need to parse as float in this case. Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried that already. it gives "1,000" again without the ".00"

Comment: i've attached image. please help

Comment: @Leguy edited my answer